# mongodb php aunthentication is not working

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I tried from all the ways it loading long time please help me out this issue

```
<?php
//Include Composer's autoloader
require_once __DIR__ . "/commons/mongo/mongodb/autoload.php";

//Create a MongoDB client and open connection to Amazon DocumentDB
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://username:password@13.212.232.159:27017,54.169.109.109:27017,54.255.203.67:27017");

//Specify the database and collection to be used
$col = $client->sampledatabase->samplecollection;

//Insert a single document
$result = $col->insertOne( [ 'hello' => 'Amazon DocumentDB'] );

//Find the document that was previously written
$result = $col->findOne(array('hello' => 'Amazon DocumentDB'));

//Print the result to the screen
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question: What have you tried so far? What error are you getting?

Comment: Same thing is working in node.js but it is not working in php

Comment: Iam trying to connect mongodb replicaset using username and password it is not giving any error but loading the page contineously after 5min it gives timeout

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge please help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Your way of connecting seems a bit off.

- I am seeing IP's instead of an Amazon Document DB Endpoint.
- I do not see the TLS file

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html), this should be the way to connect:

```
<?php
//Include Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$TLS_DIR = "/home/ubuntu/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem";

//Create a MongoDB client and open connection to Amazon DocumentDB
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://<sample-user>:<password>@sample-cluster.node.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?retryWrites=false", ["tls" => "true", "tlsCAFile" => $TLS_DIR ]);

//Specify the database and collection to be used
$col = $client->sampledatabase->samplecollection;

//Insert a single document
$result = $col->insertOne( [ 'hello' => 'Amazon DocumentDB'] );

//Find the document that was previously written
$result = $col->findOne(array('hello' => 'Amazon DocumentDB'));

//Print the result to the screen
print_r($result);
?>
```

Where `sample-cluster.node.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com` needs to be changed by your endpoint